# is there a windows equivalent of the linux command "perf stat"?

Tags: windows, perf

is there a windows equivalent of the linux command "perf stat"?  For example to see frontend stalls, cache misses and other performance counter data?

Comment: [`tasklist`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

`perf` is Linux-only profiler capable to access hardware event counters (cache miss, cpu stalls, etc). This profiler supports many CPUs, but can't be used in MS Windows.

For Windows you may try profilers from your CPU vendor:

- [VTune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTune) from/for Intel ($$$)
- [CodeAnalyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeAnalyst)/CodeXL from/for AMD (free)
- Intel PCM from/for Intel (free) - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor (needs some compilation with DDK kit to get msr.dll driver and pcm.exe tool)
- Visual Studio Profiler from Microsoft (part of Studio, some counters for several CPUs) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385772.aspx "CPU Counters", "Portable Events", [VSPerfCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182403.aspx)/VSPerfMon command line tool (it may be [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152533/196561) with some events on recent CPUs)

Comment: Note: The "Performance Explorer"  feature (and by that "CPU Counters") is only available for Visual Studio Ultimate, Visual Studio Premium and Visual Studio Professional.

Answer (score 4):

Some people who find this question might be actually looking for `xperf`, or the new ETW stuff which is replacing it which could be downloaded [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/).